# ListWheelScrollView blocking gestureDetector

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

so I've been trying to use a ListWheelScroolView in my app and I've noticed that the gesture detector from my widget CustomButton it is not working, the console say nothing about this error and I think that this is happening because the ListWheel has some conflict with the GestureDetector, does anyone nows a way to solve this?

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                  diameterRatio: 2,
                  itemExtent: 140,
                  perspective: 0.01,
                  squeeze: 1.15,
                  physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ButtonGroup(
                        CustomButton("English", "small", "en-US"),
                        CustomButton("German", "small", "de-DE"),
                        CustomButton("Danish", "small", "DA"),
                        CustomButton("Arabic", "small", "ar-EG"),
                      ),])
```

.

```
   class ButtonGroup extends StatefulWidget {
     CustomButton button1, button2, button3, button4;

     ButtonGroup(this.button1, this.button2, this.button3, this.button4);

     @override
     _ButtonGroupState createState() => _ButtonGroupState();
   }

   class _ButtonGroupState extends State<ButtonGroup> {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
         child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.button1,
          widget.button2,
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.button3,
          widget.button4,
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
     }
   }
```

'''